# Is this a saying?

Tags: korean-to-english, phrase-meaning

Sentence:

> 비나 와라. 비나 와 버려라.

Papago translates it as "Come rain. Come rain" which sounds like a saying to me. Does it mean something specific?

The paragraph is just about a guy needing to find a girl before another guy confesses to her. This is the last two sentences.

This phrase is from a book. 보건교사 안은영 by 정세랑.

Here's the paragraph:

> 너 한테 필요한 건 키만 크고 얼굴이 여드름 밭인 농구부 주장이 아니야. 매일 아침 눈빛 만 봐도 네가 매점의 서른 여섯 가지 간식들 중 뭘 먹고 싶어 하는지 아는 나라고. 승권은 농구부 주장보다 먼저 혜현을 찾아야했다. 농구부 애들이 저 질퍽한 운동장에 하트 모양으로 꽂을 초들을 가지고 왔다고했다. 비나 와라. 비나와 버려라.

Comment: where is this from? More context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

비가 오다 or 비가 내리다 means "to rain". 비(rain) is the subject here which 오다(comes) or 내리다(falls).

와라 is 오다 + -라. Verb + -라 is the form used to command or suggest someone else to do something. When used with something that cannot be commanded, it means one hopes that to happen. So, 비 와라 or 비 내려라 means "I wish it rains/it would rain".

-나 has various meanings. Here, it means that 비 is not something that is absolutely necessary in the context. So 비나 와라 means "I wish it would rain or something like that."

The speaker really means that he(she) wishes something bad happens, like rain, so that their(농구부 애들) plan fails, just because he(she) is annoyed.

Comment: This is a good answer but I have to point out that `~나` in this context does not mean `either`/`or something`. It only suggests that the speaker is dissatisfied of something (s)he gets to choose and being kinda sarcastic. See the definition of [~나](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/m/eng/searchResultView?wordMatchFlag=N&currentPage=1&mainSearchWord=나&sort=&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=89218&font_size=12&nationCode=6&nation=eng&viewType=A) in the dictionary.